# Send Data to Web Site

Tags: html, ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a problem. I  send to server a `POST` request from the program *(xcode,i developed on objective C),* data is sent,  but I need to register on the site (authentication) and i don't know ,how i sent this string

```
NSString * param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=login&name=%@&password=%@", myName, myPassword]
```

My code in full:

```
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString * myName = _loginLogin.text;
NSString * myPassword= _passwordLogin.text;

NSString * param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=login&name=%@&password=%@", myName, myPassword];
request.HTTPBody = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I work with this**( www.dnevnik.ru)** page.

and for my site string `NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&username=%@&password=%@", username, password];`  not going to be fit?

Comment: You need to parse the response in the delegate callbacks for NSURLConnectionDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Use following code :
Just add

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *responseData;
```

In your **.h** file

```
NSUserDefaults *loginData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *username = [loginData objectForKey:@"username"] ;
    NSString *password = [loginData objectForKey:@"password"];

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&username=%@&password=%@", username, password];
    NSString *urlString = @"http://YourUrl";
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *detailRequestToServer =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [detailRequestToServer setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [detailRequestToServer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    const char *utfString = [postString UTF8String];
    NSString *utfStringLenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zu", strlen(utfString)];
    [detailRequestToServer setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes: utfString length:strlen(utfString)]];
    [detailRequestToServer setValue:utfStringLenString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:detailRequestToServer delegate:self];
    if (theConnection)
    {
        self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *bodyData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=login&name=%@&password=%@", myName, myPassword];

    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"]]; //replace your url here

    // Set the request's content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Designate the request a POST request and specify its body data
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] length:strlen([bodyData UTF8String])]];

// Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
if (!theConnection) {
    // Release the receivedData object.
    receivedData = nil;

    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```